# How to load font awesome ie8 w/Font Download disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, internet-explorer-8

Ive been trying to load Font Awsome via google webfont for so it works on ie8 with the Font Download (in Internet Options>Security>Downloads) disabled. Ive been experimenting with different versions of this code but still see only empty boxes where the font should be. When I enable  Font Download the icons are there.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
<script>window.WebFont || document.write('<script src="javascripts/webfont.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script>
  WebFont.load({
    fontinactive: function (family, fvd) {
      if (family === 'Flamenco' && 'FontAwesome') {
        WebFont.load({
          custom: {
            families: ['Flamenco', 'FontAwesome'],
            urls: [ '/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css' ]
          }
        })
      }
    },
    google: {
      families: ['Flamenco'],
    },
    custom: {
      families: ['FontAwesome'],
      urls: [ '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css' ]
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: did you get any solution the above stated problem ?

Answer (score -2):

Better of using `@Font-face` in CSS when adding fonts. Done it before and works really well.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Source: [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Comment: As the user stated Font Downloading is disabled in IE and thus the CSS way of downloading fonts is not an option.